# 404 error on detailspage but Route exists in Laravel,

Tags: laravel

I get a 404 error when I try to get the details page of my services. I would like your help on how i can solve this 404 error. Thank you in advance.

`HomeController.php`

```
public function department(Request $request, $slug)
    {
         //$service=Service::where('service_slug', $slug)->first();
          $service = Service::findOrFail($slug);
          return view('client.department.departmentdetails')->with('service', $service);
          //return redirect()->route('department.show');
```

`web.php`

```
Route::get('/department/{slug}', 'HomeController@department')->name('department.show');
```

`header.php`

```
<li class="mega-menu-item">
    <a href="/departments" class="mega-menu-link">Departments</a>
       <ul class="mega-submenu">
         @foreach(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('services')->get() as $service)
         <li><a href="{{ route('department.show',$service->service_slug) }}">
          {{$service->service_name}}</a>
        </li>
         @endforeach
```

**I have Tried**

1. php artisan route:clear
2. Returning `return redirect()->route('department.show');` in the Home Controller Its now commented

**Edit**

```
public function department(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //$service=Service::where('service_slug', $slug)->first();
        //$service = Service::findOrFail($slug);
          $service = Service::findOrFail($id);
          //return view('client.department.departmentdetails')->with('service', $service);
          return redirect()->route('department.show');

        
    }
```

Comment: `$service = Service::findOrFail($slug);` `findOrFail()` takes an `id` as parameter, not a slug. Did you change your models primary key to use `service_slug`? The line you commented above that should do it

Comment: Hello, I still get the same 404 error, check the edit above.

Comment: Did you change your route to use `id` as parameter? `Route::get('/department/{id}...'` What's the URL that's causing the 404? What's the use of redirecting at the end of your method, doesn't seem to make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If your route says :

```
Route::get('/department/{id}', 'HomeController@department')->name('department.show');
```

Then in your controller you should be accessing the ID passed to the route in the URL as follows :

```
public function department(Request $request)
{
      $service = Service::findOrFail($request->id);
}
```

Your current code then returns a redirect to the same route, when you want to be returning the view :

```
    public function department(Request $request)
{
      $service = Service::findOrFail($request->id);
      return view('client.department.departmentdetails')->with('service', $service);
}
```

And, for sake of ease, you may want to compact it as follows :

```
    public function department(Request $request)
{
      $service = Service::findOrFail($request->id);
      return view('client.department.departmentdetails')->with(compact('service'));
}
```

In header.php your $service will automatically be available.